# Can't display a component in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am building a small cinema website. My issue is that I have a list, when you click the listen a button is displayed with a function, when you click that function it should give you more details on the item you have clicked. I have tried to work through the Angular Tour of Heroes again but I can't get the details to show up.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovm4h.png

The above is what is seen, some details should be shown on the page but there is no error relevant to why it is not showing.

```
`import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent }   from './dashboard.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes.component';
import { HeroService }          from './hero.service';
import { AccordionModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { AppRoutingModule }     from './app-routing.module';
import { RatingModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import { GalleriaModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { CinemaComponent} from './cinema.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact.component';
import { AgmCoreModule } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';
import { ReviewsComponent } from './reviews.component';
import { TabViewModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { CinemaService } from './cinema.service';
import { CinemaDetailComponent } from './cinema-detail.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AccordionModule,
    RatingModule,
    GalleriaModule,
    TabViewModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyDmQWd7DM4PcMvkzp_uopvIkbyjPMWzHeM'
    })
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    CinemaComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    ReviewsComponent,
    CinemaDetailComponent

  ],
  providers: [ HeroService, CinemaService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
`
```

App Module

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent }   from './dashboard.component';
import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail.component';
import { CinemaComponent } from './cinema.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact.component';
import { ReviewsComponent } from './reviews.component';
import { CinemaDetailComponent } from './cinema-detail.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard',  component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: 'heroes',     component: HeroesComponent },
  { path: 'cinema', component: CinemaComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
  { path: 'reviews', component: ReviewsComponent },
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: CinemaDetailComponent}
  ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Cinema Detail Component

```
import { Component, OnInit }      from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location }               from '@angular/common';

import { Cinema }         from './cinema';
import { CinemaService }  from './cinema.service';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-cinema-detail',
  templateUrl: 'cinema-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'cinema-detail.component.css' ]
})
export class CinemaDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  cinema: Cinema;

  constructor(
    private cinemaService: CinemaService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      let id = +params['id'];
      this.cinemaService.getCinema(id)
        .then(Cinema => this.cinema = Cinema);
    });
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

The HTML that should be displayed

```
<

div *ngIf="cinema">
  <h2>{{cinema.name}} details!</h2>
  <div>
    <label>id: </label>{{cinema.id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>name: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="cinema.name" placeholder="name" />
  </div>
  <button (click)="goBack()">Back</button>
</div>
```

My cinema.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CinemaDetailComponent } from './cinema-detail.component';
import { Cinema } from './cinema';
import { CinemaService } from './cinema.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-cinema',
  templateUrl: 'cinema.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'cinema.component.css' ]
})
export class CinemaComponent implements OnInit {
  cinemas: Cinema[];
  selectedCinema: Cinema;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private cinemaService: CinemaService) { }

  getCinemas(): void {
    this.cinemaService.getCinemas().then(cinemas => this.cinemas = cinemas);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCinemas();
  }

  onSelect(cinema: Cinema): void {
    this.selectedCinema = cinema;
  }

  gotoDetail(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/detail', this.selectedCinema.id]);
  }
}
```

cinema.service.ts file

```
import { Cinema } from './cinema';
import { CINEMAS } from './mock-cinema';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CinemaService {
  getCinemas(): Promise<Cinema[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(CINEMAS);
  }

  getHeroesSlowly(): Promise<Cinema[]> {
    return new Promise<Cinema[]>(resolve =>
      setTimeout(resolve, 2000)) // delay 2 seconds
      .then(() => this.getCinemas());
  }

  getCinema(id: number): Promise<Cinema> {
    return this.getCinemas()
               .then(cinemas => cinemas.find(cinema => cinema.id === id));
  }
}
```

Can anybody help figure out why it isn't displayed? I haven't posted the export class for Cinema which just contains an id:number and name:string or the array which is correct (as it displays the list to click on). Thanks for reading.

Comment: I forgot to include my cinema.service.ts file which is http://pastebin.com/dW08PNa5

Comment: is this angular or angular 2?  looks like angular 2 but it isn't obvious with all the code in links.  Also, questions where all the code is in links and not in the question body are not very useful, and rarely receive answers.  Links can change, leaving future readers completely unable to follow the problem.

Comment: @Claies Apologies, it's Angluar2. I will edit my question with the code, I thought it would be too long winded.

Comment: @Claies I have since updated my post with my code.

Comment: @DáithíCushen On your `CinemaDetailComponent `, try to move your `ngOnInit` logic to your `constructor`. There seems to be `ngOnInit` issue not being called. Let me know the result.

Comment: @Michael Throws an unexpected token error for 'this'.

Comment: @Michael Adding it to the {} following the constructor has gotten rid of the error, but nothing is still displated.

Comment: @DáithíCushen Good to know. What rxjs version are you using?

Comment: @Michael I have never installed RxJS so unless it came with npm (latest) then I am not using it.